# Efficient ways to save C# nested objects to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table structure which is nested to 5 levels with a one to many relationship going downwards.
I want to know what's an efficient way to save the this kind of data into the SQL Server. I now loop on each child object (C#) and run an insert which becomes slow if the data is large.

Is there a way to pass the C# directly to SQL in traditional ADO.NET? I have a custom framework which fires a SQL script for each insert, which picks up values from the object properties. I can't move to EF or NHirbernate as it's an existing project.

I have seen ways where C# objects can be inserted into DataTables and then passed to SQl, is that an efficient way?

Please advise.

Comment: I would still strongly recommend EntityFramework, even though you say it's not a desirable option. It makes life easier.

Comment: You can check the option for serialize objects to xml and pass xml to sql server. In sql server you can parse the xml and insert respectively.

Comment: Take a look at Table Valued Parameters for SQL Server 2008 and above - but you will have to take care of the flattening of the hierarchy to a data table.

Comment: I agree with @Maritim, there is no other way to do it, if you want to change all your queries the workload is similar to move to EF. I don't know how you implemented your queries, but an efficient way would be to include all your dependant queries inside the same transaction, that will improve performance

Comment: Even if you need to save existing objects, there are some ways to use Entity Framework against. And if it's not possible, it's easy to generate objects related to database and map your existing objects to EF ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have something like this from a database perspective

```
CREATE TABLE Items (ID INT -- primary key, 
                    Name VARCHAR(MAX),
                    ParentID INT) -- foreign key that loops on the same table
```

and an object like this in C#

```
public class Item
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int ParentID {get; set;}
   public Item Parent {get; set;}
   public List<Item> Children {get; set;}
}
```

and you have some code that looks like:

```
var root = MakeMeATree();
databaseSaver.SaveToDatabase(root);
```

that generates an insert-per-item for every child. If you have lots of children, this can really slow up the application.

What I would use (and have used) in this case is a custom sql server type and a stored procedure to save the whole thing in a single call.

You will need to create a type that matches the table:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ItemType AS TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(MAX),
    ParentID INT
);
```

and a simple procedure that uses the type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertItems
(
  @Items AS dbo.ItemType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SampleTable(ID, Name, ParentID)
  SELECT ID, Name, ParentID From @Items
END
```

Now, that does it from the SQL Server side. Now on to the C# side. You need to do two things:

1. Flatten the hierarchy into a list
2. Sent that list as a datatable to the database

The first can be done using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117404/searching-hierarchical-list/2118192#2118192) (I use [this](https://gist.github.com/sweko/8096992), which is basically the same thing), with a simple

```
var items = root.Flatten(i => i.Children);
```

To do the second thing, first you need to declare the SQL Server type as a datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Items"); 
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int)); 
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)); 
dt.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
```

next, just fill the values:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   dt.Rows.Add(item.ID, item.Name, item.ParentID);
}
```

and attach them to a `SqlParameter`, that should be of the `SqlDbType.Structured` type, like this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertItems", connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var itemsParam = new SqlParameter("@Items", SqlDbType.Structured);
    itemsParam .Value = dt;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(itemsParam);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And, that should be it.

Comment: interesting approach! Not suitable for all cases, but deserves a try.

Comment: Will this work in the case of an insert? Say, if the hierarchy is new to the database? Or even if a part of the hierarchy is new?

Answer (score -1):

Yes this if you want your Dataset Objects to be stored in the DataBase u can go with optionslike 
Create a SQL  UserDefinedType object.
Fill the Object the requierd values and the  read the Value in the Stored procedure AND Fill the object value in the Temp and using your business logic u can stored in Db.